# Robust atomic file copying

Tags: python-3.x, atomic, file-copying

I currently have

```
def _atomic_copyfile(src, dst, overwrite):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(dst),
                                     delete=False) as tmp_h:
        with open(src, 'rb') as src_fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc=src_fd,
                               fdst=tmp_h)
    if overwrite:
        # works both on Windows and Linux from Python 3.3+, os.rename raises an
        # exception on Windows if the file exists
        os.replace(src=tmp_h.name,
                   dst=dst)
    else:
        if not os.path.exists(dst):
            os.rename(src=tmp_h.name,
                      dst=dst)
```

How do I make the temporary file `tmp_h` be removed automatically if an exception is thrown or a signal is caught?

Note that I can't use `delete=True` because the temporary file is renamed.

Comment: what's wrong with protecting the whole block with a big `try/except` and try to delete`tmp_h.name` (protect the remove by an exception handler)

Answer (score 0):

What should work (I normally wouldn't use `try/except:` without any exception but in that case it applies, well maybe you'd like to add a message, traceback, whatever, in the `except` case):

```
def _atomic_copyfile(src, dst, overwrite):
    try:
       with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(dst),
                                       delete=False) as tmp_h:
       # your current code
    except:
        # maybe print something here to notify that an error occured
        # instead of masking it
        pass
    finally:
        try:
           os.remove(tmp_h.name)
        except:
           pass
```

That code in the `finally` section tries to remove the file. If it fails, catch the exception and do nothing (for instance if the file doesn't exist or was renamed, or even: `tmp_h` variable doesn't exist yet)

`os.remove` may, of course, fail even if the file already exists, but unlikely because since you're out of the `with` context, the file is closed already.

Comment: Are you sure that `tmp_h` will be defined in the finally scope?

Comment: no I'm not sure, but my answer covers it "or even: tmp_h variable doesn't exist yet": you'll get an exception and you'll trap it, like any other one